# Bluetooth from the Command Line

Tags: command-line, cross-platform, bluetooth, platform-agnostic

How do I access files on another device/machine over Bluetooth from the command line?

Comment: This do not seem platform-agnotisc at all.

Comment: I meant from any OS: Windows/Apples/Unices/Linuces

Comment: Not programming related . . .

Comment: Jerome is right, thats not platform-agnostic anyway, since every os has its own hal.

Comment: Three votes to close! What if I were trying to write a script/batch-file to access files over Bluetooth? Wouldn't that be programming related? Do I have to spell it out to you chaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bct) suite for Windows. This suite of tools contains a **btftp** utility that allows you to exchanges files with remote Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Hard to understand why more people don't know about this.

Comment: The Bluetooth Command Line Tools suite is very well made, but it is freeware and not opensource. Anyone can comment about its safety? A quick scan in Windows Defender finds no treat, though.

Answer (score 8):

In the debian package, there is `bluez-utils` package. It contains several command line tools as:

- hcitool: configure Bluetooth connections. e.g. `$ hcitool dev` will list the devices
- hciconfig: configure Bluetooth devices. Once you found a device, you can configure it.

They may exist commands for sending, receive etc... from/to Bluetooth devices.