# Turning Bluetooth On/Off using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, bluetooth

I want to turn my computer's Bluetooth on/off using a python script. This is what I have found on the internet so far :

```
import os
os.system("rfkill block bluetooth")
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I have a windows computer. Does anyone know the `os.system()` command to on/off Bluetooth? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756555/bluetooth-from-the-command-line

Comment: but i want to do it in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limited Bluetooth functionality available with the [Windows Runtime Python Projection](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/). Python/WinRT enables Python developers to access Windows Runtime APIs directly from Python in a natural and familiar way.

I was able to turn the Bluetooth radio off and on with the following code:

```py
import asyncio
from winrt.windows.devices import radios


async def bluetooth_power(turn_on):
    all_radios = await radios.Radio.get_radios_async()
    for this_radio in all_radios:
        if this_radio.kind == radios.RadioKind.BLUETOOTH:
            if turn_on:
                result = await this_radio.set_state_async(radios.RadioState.ON)
            else:
                result = await this_radio.set_state_async(radios.RadioState.OFF)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(bluetooth_power(False))
```

Answer (score 1):

rfkill is Linux terminal cmnd tool for enabling and disabling wireless devices, so logically that doesn't work on windows.

for working on Bluetooth with python I recommend u to use [PyBluez](https://pybluez.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) python library

here is a sample code for read the local Bluetooth device address :

```
import bluetooth

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(bluetooth.read_local_bdaddr())
```